# Selecting Journals or Conferences to publish research work

Tags: publications, journals, conference

I am working on a multidisciplinary subject which involves mechanical engineering, chemical engineering and chemistry. I have a decent amount of research completed and now I need to select a journal to publish my work. How do I select a good journal to publish my papers?
Also for the same topic I need to select conference to present. How do I select that too?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In general if you are looking for a journal where to publish a specific type of manuscript do a survey of the material you have referenced. Where are those articles published? You should pay special attention to articles that are multidisciplinary such as yours. The next step if you are uncertain about the appropriateness is to e-mail the journal editors of journals and ask if they consider multidisciplinary articles. I do not think you should send the manuscript to them because they usually do not have time to read anything substantial just to answer a question but do paste in your title, author list and abstract.

As of conferences, I cannot see a patented answer. If a conference is a recurring event you can always go back to collections of abstracts to see if other multidisciplinary papers have been presented. Another option is to see if you cannot organize your own session at a larger conference that permits sessions.

Answer (score 0):

If the journal accepts pre-submission inquires try this way.

Alternatively consult [Elsevier Matching](http://www.elsevier.com/journal-authors/home) tool, it should help.

Comment: Don't use Elsevier Matching, because (a) it's not very good, (b) it is **restricted to Elsevier journals**, which form a minority of the journals in many fields

Comment: Well, one can also use Springer Marching tool and compare. But surely, some of journals that are most reputable in the community might be published elsewhere. http://www.springer.com/authors/journal+authors/journal+authors+academy?SGWID=0-1726414-12-837833-0