# How can I get my papers published formally?

Tags: publications, grey-literature

I have posted majority of my academic work from MA program on Academia.edu. This past week I had the time to look into the  Analytics section and I have tons of followers, readers, downloads, student citing my work etc. Enough readers that I think I should try to get my work published.

How do I get my work published formally? Who should I try to reach out to? My informally published work is getting a lot of traffic.

Any suggestions on how to do that?

Answer (score 4):

1. Choose a target journal. A good first step is to see where the papers you cite are published.Some other suggestions are [here](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/60350/how-to-select-a-journal-for-publishing) and [here](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/37344/how-does-one-figure-out-which-journals-to-submit-a-paper-to). If you don't have a budget for publishing, look for one that has no author fees. Avoid predatory and low-quality journals; see [how to judge the quality of a journal](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/101/how-do-you-judge-the-quality-of-a-journal).
2. Visit the target journal's website, and read about the scope of the journal and their instructions for authors. Read some papers in the latest issue of their journal. Make sure your paper is on topic, and is comparable to other recent papers in the journal in scope, writing quality, and rigor. If it's not a good fit, go back to step 1.
3. Edit your paper to follow the instructions for authors from step 2 (formatting, length, anonymizing if the journal does double-blind review.)
4. Submit the paper to the journal for review, following the instructions on the journal's website.
5. Watch your paper go through the [journal workflow](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/55665/what-does-the-typical-workflow-of-a-journal-look-like).